How does ἀναψύξεως in Acts 3:20 reflect the eschatological hope of messianic 'rest' in Peter's preaching, based on the LXX and Second Temple Judaism?
How does the term ἀναψύξεως [SG403 anapsyxeōs, "of refreshing" - ed.] in Acts 3:20 reflect the eschatological hope of messianic 'rest' in the context of Peter's preaching, given its roots in the LXX and Second Temple Jewish thought?
ASV  Acts 3:19

Repent ye therefore, and turn again, that your sins may be blotted out, that so there may come seasons of refreshing from the presence of the Lord; 20 and that he may send the Christ who hath been appointed for you, even Jesus:

BGT  Acts 3:20

ὅπως ἂν ἔλθωσιν καιροὶ ἀναψύξεως ἀπὸ προσώπου τοῦ κυρίου καὶ ἀποστείλῃ τὸν προκεχειρισμένον ὑμῖν χριστὸν Ἰησοῦν,


Textual Matter
There is a difference between the verse divisions in some versions:

Acts 3:19, 20 - Repent, then, and turn back, so that your sins may be
wiped away, that times of refreshing may come from the presence of
the Lord, and that He may send Jesus, the Christ, who has been
appointed for you.


some versions place the highlighted text above in V19 and others place it in V20.

In either case, the phrase καιροὶ ἀναψύξεως (= "times of refreshing") is unique in the NT as is the noun ἀνάψυξις = "refreshment".
Two Views on Acts 3:19, 20
There are two widely spread views about what Acts 3:19, 20 actually means - there are:
1. The "Times of Refreshing" = Living the Christian Life with Christ
This view is based on the obvious and immediate meaning of the text of Acts 3:19, 20; that following the process outlined -

repent
turn back (ie, "convert" to use the Christian technical term")
enjoy times of refreshing that comes from the presence (literally the "facing") of the Lord Jesus Christ as per the "abiding" of Christ in the Christian life as per John 15:4-7, 9-10, 17:23, 26, Eph 2:6, etc.

2. The "Times of Refreshing" = Return of Jesus at the end times
Some interpret this passage eschatologically (as per the OP's question), presumably on the basis of 1 Cor 13:10 about the coming of "perfection/completion".
While this is certainly possible, we also have Heb 4 1-11 offering an extended discussion about the rest possible "Today" (V7) and entering God's rest in the presence of Jesus in our lives.
Now, it is also possible that both meanings are intended as Ellicott correctly points out:

The “times of refreshing” are distinguished from the “restitution of
all things” of Acts 3:21, and would seem to be, as it were, the
gracious preludes of that great consummation. The souls of the weary
would be quickened as by the fresh breeze of morning; the fire of
persecution assuaged as by “a moist whistling wind” (Song of the Three
Children, Acts 3:24). Israel, as a nation, did not repent, and
therefore hatred and strife went on to the bitter end without
refreshment. For every church, or nation, or family, those “times of
refreshing” come as the sequel of a true conversion, and prepare the
way for a more complete restoration.

Barnes also places this in historical context:

Times of refreshing - The word rendered "refreshing," ἀνάψυξις anapsuxis, means properly "breathing," or "refreshment," after being
heated with labor, running, etc. It hence denotes "any kind of
refreshment, as rest, or deliverance from evils of any kind." It is
used nowhere else in the New Testament, except that the verb is used
in 2 Timothy 1:16, "Onesiphorus ...oft refreshed me, and was not
ashamed of my chain." ... The idea, however, that the times of the
Messiah would be times of rest, ease, and prosperity, was a favorite
one among the Jews, and was countenanced in the Old Testament. See
Isaiah 28:12, "To whom he said, This is the rest wherewith ye may
cause the weary to rest; and this is the refreshing," etc. They
anticipated the times of the gospel as a period when they would have
rest from their enemies, a respite from the evils of oppression and
war, and great national prosperity and peace. Under the idea that the
happy times of the Messiah had come, Peter now addresses them, and
assures them that they might obtain pardon and peace.

